# How do you measure 4 categories for bar chart?

Tags: android

Please understand that I absolutely do not have an error. But my problem is that I don't understand how to divide this percentage question. So, I have a class called Bill, and each bill has its own price. (my app is an expenditure tracker). So I have PieChart in my view, i wanna know how to measure percentage per category, as each bill has its own category. There are 4 categories -:

1. Groceries
2. Trips
3. Loans/Bills/Other
4. Shopping

Each is summed upto a price, And i don't understand how to track
each one into pie chart out of 100 %.

```
    package com.functionality.mylifehelper.drawerUI.ui.expenditure;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ExpensesManager {
List<Bill> bills;
Earning obj;

/**
 * Prices
 */
int allPrices;

int pricesForGroceries;
int pricesForLoansEtc;
int pricesForTripsEtc;
int pricesForShopping;

int percentageGroceries;
int percentageLoans;
int percentageTrips;
int percentageShopping;

int total = 100;
List<Bill> TYPE_1, TYPE_2, TYPE_3, TYPE_4;
ExpensesManager(List<Bill> expenses, Earning earning) {
    bills=expenses;
    obj=earning;
    calculateCost();
}

private void calculateCost() {
    List<Bill> groceries = new ArrayList<>(), loans = new ArrayList<>(), trips
            = new ArrayList<>(), shopping = new ArrayList<>();
    for(Bill bill : bills) {
        if(bill.getType().equals(Bill.food)) {
            groceries.add(bill);
            pricesForGroceries += bill.getAmount();
        } else if(bill.getType().equals(Bill.loans)) {
            pricesForLoansEtc += bill.getAmount();
            loans.add(bill);
        } else if(bill.getType().equals(Bill.shopping)) {
            pricesForShopping += bill.getAmount();
            shopping.add(bill);
        } else {
            pricesForTripsEtc += bill.getAmount();
            trips.add(bill);
        }
    }
    TYPE_1 = groceries;
    TYPE_2 = loans;
    TYPE_3 = trips;
    TYPE_4 = shopping;

    total = bills.size();

    // tasks : 10

    // say there are 90 tasks
    // for e.g only - >
    // NOW, YOU SAY THAT 50 are groceries, 10 loans etc
    //
    // groceries = 90 / 50 = 45.000 something
    percentageGroceries = total / percentageGroceries;
    percentageLoans = total / percentageLoans;

}

public int getAllItemsCost() {
    return pricesForGroceries+pricesForTripsEtc+pricesForShopping+pricesForLoansEtc;
}
```

}

Comment: You said it in the last question. The percentage per category will be the sum of all of its costs for the category in comparison to the sum of everything. Let's say that you had a budget of 100, you spent 20 on shopping. `per caterogory` 20 to `sum of everything` 100. The result will be `0.2`. If you want percentage you need to multiplty it by 100.

Comment: Even I know, @Juanid Khalid, but i don't quite know maths,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll thank you for the comments, but this is what worked eventually:

```
    package com.functionality.mylifehelper.drawerUI.ui.expenditure;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ExpensesManager {
List<Bill> bills;
Earning obj;

/**
 * Prices
 */
int allPrices;

int pricesForGroceries;
int pricesForLoansEtc;
int pricesForTripsEtc;
int pricesForShopping;

int percentageGroceries;
int percentageLoans;
int percentageTrips;
int percentageShopping;

int total = 100;
List<Bill> TYPE_1, TYPE_2, TYPE_3, TYPE_4;
ExpensesManager(List<Bill> expenses, Earning earning) {
    bills=expenses;
    obj=earning;
    calculateCost();
}

public List<Bill> getBills() {
    return bills;
}

public Earning getObj() {
    return obj;
}

public int getAllPrices() {
    return allPrices;
}

public int getPricesForGroceries() {
    return pricesForGroceries;
}

public int getPricesForLoansEtc() {
    return pricesForLoansEtc;
}

public int getPricesForTripsEtc() {
    return pricesForTripsEtc;
}

public int getPricesForShopping() {
    return pricesForShopping;
}

public int getPercentageGroceries() {
    return percentageGroceries;
}

public int getPercentageLoans() {
    return percentageLoans;
}

public int getPercentageTrips() {
    return percentageTrips;
}

public int getPercentageShopping() {
    return percentageShopping;
}

public int getTotal() {
    return total;
}

public List<Bill> getTYPE_1() {
    return TYPE_1;
}

public List<Bill> getTYPE_2() {
    return TYPE_2;
}

public List<Bill> getTYPE_3() {
    return TYPE_3;
}

public List<Bill> getTYPE_4() {
    return TYPE_4;
}

private void calculateCost() {
    List<Bill> groceries = new ArrayList<>(), loans = new ArrayList<>(), trips
            = new ArrayList<>(), shopping = new ArrayList<>();
    for(Bill bill : bills) {
        if(bill.getType().equals(Bill.food)) {
            groceries.add(bill);
            pricesForGroceries += bill.getAmount();
        } else if(bill.getType().equals(Bill.loans)) {
            pricesForLoansEtc += bill.getAmount();
            loans.add(bill);
        } else if(bill.getType().equals(Bill.shopping)) {
            pricesForShopping += bill.getAmount();
            shopping.add(bill);
        } else {
            pricesForTripsEtc += bill.getAmount();
            trips.add(bill);
        }
    }
    TYPE_1 = groceries;
    TYPE_2 = loans;
    TYPE_3 = trips;
    TYPE_4 = shopping;

    total = bills.size();

    // tasks : 10

    // say there are 90 tasks
    // for e.g only - >
    // NOW, YOU SAY THAT 50 are groceries, 10 loans etc
    //
    // groceries = 90 / 50 = 45.000 something
    try {
        percentageGroceries = total / TYPE_1.size();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        percentageGroceries = 0;
    }
    try {
        percentageLoans = total / TYPE_2.size();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        percentageLoans = 0;
    }
    try {
        percentageShopping = total / TYPE_4.size();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        percentageShopping = 0;
    }
    try {
        percentageTrips = total / TYPE_3.size();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        percentageTrips = 0;
    }
}

public int getAllItemsCost() {
    return pricesForGroceries+pricesForTripsEtc+pricesForShopping+pricesForLoansEtc;
}
```

}

Thank you for your suggestion, @TheLibrarian, but I got it before you, :) i'm signing off, don't forget to upvote and use it for yourself.

Comment: Please remember, use org.eazegraph.blackfizz lib, idk abt rest